# AttributeError: 'BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Tags: pyspark

```
Bin_evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()

classifier = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'isFraud')
fitModel = classifier.fit(train)

predictionAndLabels = fitModel.evaluate(test)
auc = Bin_evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels)

print("AUC: " ,auc)
```

This is in PySpark. I keep getting the error, AttributeError: 'BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary' object has no attribute '_jdf'. How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: why are you calling `evaluate` on `fitModel`? That shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
auc = Bin_evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels.predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol="prediction",labelCol="label")
accuracy=evaluator.evaluate(predictions_and_labels.predictions)
print("accuracy : ",accuracy*100," %")
```